# HTTP in Java socket

Tags: java, sockets, http, header

I want to send a JSON to an already written server (not from me).
My problem is that I have an HTTP problem and need to convert it to HTTP.

Server message:

```
2018-06-29 20:02:30.532:WARN:oejh.HttpParser:qtp245475541-15: badMessage: 400 
No URI for HttpChannelOverHttp@2bb4ec27{r=0,c=false,a=IDLE,uri=}
2018-06-29 20:03:24.206:WARN:oejh.HttpParser:qtp245475541-18: badMessage: 400 
No URI for HttpChannelOverHttp@866a0c9{r=0,c=false,a=IDLE,uri=}
```

Code:

```
public class client {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JsonObject js = new JsonObject();
        js.addProperty("action","auth");
        js.addProperty("type","android");
        js.addProperty("token","lalalalalalalalala");
        try {
            Socket ss = new Socket("localhost",3000);
            PrintWriter out =
                    new PrintWriter(ss.getOutputStream(), true);
                BufferedReader in =
                    new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(ss.getInputStream()));
            out.println(js.toString());// sending json

            System.out.println(in.readLine()); //recieving answer

        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Output on console: `HTTP/1.1 400 No URI`.

Comment: Don't use a `Socket`, use an `HttpURLConnection`.

Answer (score 1):

Writing your own HTTP client from scratch is doable, but it's not simple. Check out this link: [Java Tutorials: URLConnection](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/urls/readingWriting.html). That is going to save you a lot of effort.